# Set user as super user from db

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, database, phpmyadmin

Joomla 3.3.6

I have a user called 'Jo'. He is currently set as a Joomla 'Administrator' with front and back-end access. However I would like to now set him as a 'Super User'. How can I achieve this via the database?

Reason for doing this is because I don't have access to the super admin account, however I do have access the the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was very cautious about this question and nearly flagged it as a security hole, but re-read it.

You mentioned you have access to the database, so assuming the Super User group ID had not been changed in any way, you can open the `#__user_usergroup_map` table, find the `user_id` that corresponds to your user, and change the `group_id` to `8` which is the default ID for the Super User group.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the super user group will have ID 8?